# Android disable Sliding Panel Layout on specific condition

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I am using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) on my project .  I want to disable sliding on specific condition . So that only top part is visible , and dragging is disabled .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(condition){
   mSlidingLayout.setEnabled(false);
   mSlidingLayout.setClickable(false);
}
```

if the above code doesn't work then try like

```
if(condition){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          mSlidingLayout.setEnabled(false);
          mSlidingLayout.setClickable(false);
        }
    });                    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

to lock your DrawerLayout so it won't be able to open with gestures. And unlock it with:

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);`

Comment: Here is nothing about drawerLayout